# Изменение регистра букв с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Дана строка, состоящая из слов, разделенных пробелами. Сформировать новую строку, в которой все слова в нижнем регистре, кроме первой буквы первого слова.

Пробовал через `re.sub` заменять, это единственное, что в голову пришло. Я должен искать все символы в строке и заменять их на такой  же, но в нижнем регистре, `sub` вроде как это и делает, но какие параметры ему передавать я не очень понимаю.

Comment: Вам шашечки или ехать? Зачем регулярные выражения?

Comment: Задание такое. Надо через регулярки. А я их совсем не понимаю.

Comment: Ок, понял. Но если за вас задание сделать, вы ведь не начнёте их от этого понимать. Расскажите хоть, что пытались сделать, с чем затруднения?

Comment: вы своим уточнением запутали. что вам нужно? заменить первый символ строки? или "искать все символы в строке и заменять их на такой же"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Решение 1 - метод .capitalize()**

Используйте метод [.capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize), регулярные выражения здесь не нужны

```
>>> string = 'my favourite cool string'
>>> string.capitalize()
'My favourite cool string''
```

**Решение 2 - через регулярные выражения**

Данный способ никто в здравом уме использовать не будет, много лишних действий, только если в качестве изучения возможностей языка и регулярных выражений

Несколько шагов:

1. Вам нужно использовать метод [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) модуля re питона для замены части строки.
2. Заменять будем первый символ строки, который соответствует регулярному выражению '^\w' - один символ (цифра или буква) в начале строки.
3. Замена будет производиться на это же символ в верхнем регистре (используем метод [.upper()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) для первого символа string[:1].

```py
>>> string = 'my favourite cool string'
>>> import re
>>> new_string = re.sub(r'^\w', string[:1].upper(), string)
>>> new_string
'My favourite cool string'
```

Полезные ссылки для понимания регулярных выражений: [раз](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/), [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115825/), [три](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115436/)

И помните - "если разработчик задумал решить одну проблему через регулярные выражения, поздравляем, теперь у него есть 2 проблемы".

Comment: через методы строк не подойдет, нужно именно через регулярные выражения

Comment: @Mr.AlexC расшрил ответ

Comment: На вход regex нужно `s.casefold()` передавать (ввод не обязан в нижнем регистре быть). Если нельзя методами строк пользоваться, то и индексированием и `.upper()` также нельзя пользоваться. Если алфавит не ограничить, то задача резко усложняется и сводится к реализации `capitalize()` только с помощью регулярных выражений (не глядя в Unicode стандарт, не могу даже сказать возможно ли это—хотя вероятно достаточно первую букву заменить, используя одну большую таблицу, а остальные буквы заменить, используя другую таблицу: реализация Upper и casefold соответственно). Хотя для учёбы  ascii достаточно

Comment: @jfs да, тут вообще задача непонятная. скорее всего какая-то искуственная задача по обучению, где нужно в каком-нибудь виде применить регулярки. а вам спасибо за просвещение,

Comment: я посмотрел на Unicode стандарт: достаточно двух простых файлов [`UnicodeData.txt`](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) и [`SpecialCasing.txt`](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt) хотя некоторые правила интересны: `'Σa'.lower() == 'σa'`, но  `'aΣ'.lower() == 'aς'` (если Σ в конце слова, то другой результат)  и конечно (известное) `"ß".upper() == 'SS'`. [`pycasefold` модуль, реализующий `unicode.casefold` для Питона 2](https://goo.gl/bIflHJ), читая `CaseFolding.txt` показывает как просто подобные файлы распознавать. `s = re.sub(r'^(\w)(.*)', capitalize, s)`

Comment: где `capitalize = lamba m: upper_start_of_word(m.group(1)) + lower_anywhere(m.group(2))` (`re` модуль не поддерживает repeated captures поэтому игнорируем различия в результатах в начале/конце слов—можно `regex` модуль использовать, чтобы правильное соответствие в этом случае находить). Где `upper_start_of_word=lambda c: _upper_mapping.get(c,c)`, где `_upper_mapping` это словарь (NFDchar -> UPPER), созданный из `UnicodeData.txt` и `SpecialCasing.txt`. В общем, используя `regex.sub` и пару словарей можно выполнить задачу из заголовка вопроса, но это плохой вариант реализации `str.capitalize()`.

Comment: @jfs в общем, если правильно понял. мы должны иметь две большие базы - символы в нижнем регистре и их написания в верхнем регистре?

Comment: @while1pass есть символы, к которым понятие верхнего нижнего регистра неприменимо, но в целом верно: всё сводится к паре словарей, созданных из UnicodeData.txt и SpecialCasing.txt